# JQuery replace() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, sqlite, web-sql

I want to remove single quote character in query string which include user input. So, I replace the single quote by double quote such as:

From: `select * from user where name = "Jon'h"`
Change to: `Select * from user where name = "Jon''h"`
In jquery, I use `replace("'","''")` to do this but It can't replace multiple single quote characters. For example, `Jon'h` is change to `Jon''h` successful, but `His's boy's` will change to `His''s boy's`. The later single quotes will not be replaced.

Please help!

Comment: replace is a standard JavaScript function, not a jQuery one.

Comment: Please tell me you are not actually changing sql in the Javascript and then actually executing it.

Comment: please, please, please tell me you aren't sanitizing/creating your queries in javascript. I want to believe that you know not to do this, but thats what it looks like

Comment: why do you surprise about that? I am developing a phonegap app, I use jQuery (javascript) to handle user input, build queries and execute with Web SQL database. What mistake did I make?

Comment: Your mistake is that you did not use parameters: `var input = "Jon'h"; tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ?", [input]);`

Comment: I tried. And now I still have headache because the parameter sometime works, sometime doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex and the `g` flag :

```
var sql = sql.replace(/'/g,"''")
```